# Inspecting HTML source to identify element tags

Tags: javascript, html

I need help finding the sign in button name of a web form. What tool can I use to find this name/id, and how should I go about using that tool?

I am trying to find a way to identify the ID references for username, password and submit to automate logging into the website using javascript as in this video:[VB.NET Tutorial 41 - Website Login (Visual Basic 2008/2010)](http://youtu.be/9EJXzWasTq4)

The website is http://grooveshark.com/#!/signin

Comment: Do you have any more infomation than that? We can't mind read and need clear infomation about what you are trying to do, what problem you are having and what you have tried so far to fix it

Comment: If thats what your trying, the njust replace the yahoo.com/signing url for your's : http://grooveshark.com/#!/signin

Comment: I can't find the button name for the sign in button. I'm trying to make my program auto click the button but without the button name, I can't.

Comment: Please show your code and what you are trying.  Other people can't learn from your problem if you don't explain what it is by showing what you tried. As a question-asker, you can give back to the community by writing awesome questions. Use this [edit] link to add in your code. Good luck! :)

Comment: The button name on which page, the grooveshark page, or yours? is this with javascipt in which case you may want to tag your question as javascript too

Comment: Watch the youtube video, you'll see what i'm trying to do, problem is, I can't locate the "Sign in" button name. ( it's not "sign in", tried already)

Comment: But only add in relevant code, like maybe the HTML form of Grooveshark's login page, and your code.... hope this helps!

Comment: The Youtube video might not be up a year from now, when 100 other people have a similar problem.  Please add in your code. The video is nice and all, but if it were to break or you were to take it down, this post would be useless to all of the future visitors with a similar problem. Please add in the code. Good luck!

Comment: The grooveshark page. The sign in page has a "Sign in" button. I need the name of that button. That is the problem i'm having.

Comment: I understand that, *but you need to post the code here in the body of your post*; otherwise, the post is going to get closed by the community since it will not be helpful to future visitors.  I'd like to help, but I and many others will not visit a link outside Stack Overflow to understand a problem. Please add in your code. I'm going to stop posting comments now, but I hope it's clear that all you have to do to get help and keep this post from getting closed is post the code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use firefox web developer view to find this information:

For reference the login id is "header-login-username" and the password id is "header-login-password". The login button ID is "header-login-submit"

[image: ScreenShot]

This is some helpful information for using the web console to inspect pages which I used to find the relevant information:

[Firefox Web Developer Tool](http://www.howtogeek.com/105320/how-to-use-firefoxs-web-developer-tools/)

Comment: Hi o0rebelious, I edited the question a bit, based on your answer, to try to make it useful to future visitors. If you have any more to add to my edits to make it a more useful question, and also preserve your contribution, please feel free to make further suggested edits. Good luck! :)

Comment: You're more than welcome. In order to help as many future visitors could you edit your original question/accept any modifications in order to be as useful and helpful as possible

Comment: Thanks for editing it, i'm on my mobile and it wouldn't let me. Once again, much appreciated.